# Iteration of max heapify in heap sort

Tags: c++, heap

I have come accross heap sort , and i came to this source code

```
/ C++ program for implementation of Heap Sort
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// To heapify a subtree rooted with node i which is
// an index in arr[]. n is size of heap
void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i)
{
    int largest = i;  // Initialize largest as root
    int l = 2*i + 1;  // left = 2*i + 1
    int r = 2*i + 2;  // right = 2*i + 2

    // If left child is larger than root
    if (l < n && arr[l] > arr[largest])
        largest = l;

    // If right child is larger than largest so far
    if (r < n && arr[r] > arr[largest])
        largest = r;

    // If largest is not root
    if (largest != i)
    {
        swap(arr[i], arr[largest]);

        // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree
        heapify(arr, n, largest);
    }
}

// main function to do heap sort
void heapSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    // Build heap (rearrange array)
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(arr, n, i);

    // One by one extract an element from heap
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        // Move current root to end
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }
}

/* A utility function to print array of size n */
void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    heapSort(arr, n);

    cout << "Sorted array is \n";
    printArray(arr, n);
}
```

I understand that to build a max heap , we need to iterate from n/2 to 0 index in order to get through all elements in array. But why in heapsort , when we put root at the end , last element at the start , and reduce the size of the heap , we iteratre only from one index ?

using

```
   for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        // Move current root to end
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }
```

why will this create max heap when creating original max heap we had to iterate over n/2 elements ?

```
for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    heapify(arr, n, i);
```

why isnt heapsort declared as

```
  for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        // Move current root to end
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        for( int j = n/2 ,; j >= 0 ; j-- )
            heapify(arr, i, j);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because once the heap is constructed, you can remove the root and readjust the heap quickly, by taking advantage of the structure.

It's easiest to see that by looking at an example. Consider this heap:

```
       0
    1     3
   2 4   6 5
```

If you swap the root with the last item in the heap, you get:

```
       5
    1     3
   2 4   6 0
```

And you reduce the count by 1. Now it's time to readjust the heap from the top down. The rule is that if the item you're looking at is larger than either child, then swap it with the smallest child. So:

```
       1
    5     3
   2 4   6 0
```

And again . . .

```
       1
    2     3
   5 4   6 0
```

The heap is once again valid.

The key here is that when you replace the root node, you only have to adjust a few nodes. This *always* works. The adjustment will affect at most `log(n)` nodes (basically, the height of the tree). There's no need to rebuild the entire heap when most of it isn't affected.